# How can I spoof the time when running a webpack/react app (only for testing)?

Tags: reactjs, date, webpack

I have had a user report an issue where between midnight and 1am, some of my app's functions don't work correctly.
To recreate these issues, I would either need to just wait til midnight to fix them, or somehow emulate the time so the app thinks it's midnight. Is there a way I can do this without changing my Windows system time, or preferably without using a VM? My current technologies are

- Windows 10
- React 17.0.1
- Webpack 5.9.0

I am open to using more npm packages if required. Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question here. There is a chrome extension here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-timezone-time-shif/nbofeaabhknfdcpoddmfckpokmncimpj/related?hl=en that will quickly change your timezone in a current browser session. Hope someone else finds this useful